# Custom Tab-Shaped Plug

Tags: design, low-power, hardware

I'm designing a device that plugs into a base and am looking for clip-like part that will take a metal tab and transfer a small current (5V) to an LED in the device. The user should be able to pull the device off easily, but still have good enough contact to supply power.

Please see my very rough mockup:
[image]

What design consideration should I have in mind?

Comment: Some vague connector choice?

Comment: yes some kind of quick-disconnect connector

Comment: not enough physical and electrical details to choose from a million connectors.

Comment: Something on the order of 1" square tab that will have 3-5V (via a Raspberry Pi) running through it to power an LED. Any other details that would help?

Comment: Yes . PCB thruhole?  edge mount?  just to power an LED? which?  give a photo example. This must already exist. Maybe describe purpose in detail.  You have power for Pi and separate plug for LED which is part of clip>?

Comment: why not just use a basic card-edge connector?

Comment: The Pi will power the LED via a 3.3V output, and I want to have the connector in between the output and a 5mm LED (with a 330 Ohm resistor). I'm envisioning a tab shape of some thickness to provide some structural stability. The connector could snap/click into place, but should easily disconnect via a pulling motion. Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option I can think of is a simple pcb edge connector.  The device would have the edge of a PCB sticking out, with suitable copper pads on it.

The clip would use an off-the-shelf card edge connector to make contact with the PCB.

If polarity isn't a problem, just a big copper pad on each side of the PCB would do.  Otherwise a cunning arrangement of copper "fingers", lining up with the contacts in the edge connector, such that the polarity remains correct even if the device is plugged in the opposite way wound.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple pin header in the base and corresponding female socket on the LED will do just fine for you.

I'd suggest beefing up the top of the base to about 5mm by gluing some plastic on the inside, then making rectangular hole just big enough for socket to slide in. This would ensure easy mating of the connector.

Also, if you use 3-pin connector with 2 pins on the sides wired together you wouldn't have to bother with polarity.

[image]